# How to draw a distance-distribution diagram of a distance-regular graph in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

How to draw a distance-distribution diagram of a distance-regular graph in latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you have tried so far ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new here, here comes a possible way to do such things. Generally such questions have a high chance of remaining unanswered as no one is really keen on punching in all the text from a screen shot.(**EDIT**: added `,every label/.style={font=\small}` as suggested by AndréC.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mycirc/.style={circle,draw,fill=white,minimum
size=1cm},every label/.style={font=\small}]
\draw (0,0) node[mycirc,label={[anchor=north west]0:$k$}]{1}
-- ++ (2.7,0)node[mycirc,label={[anchor=north east]180:$1$},
label={[anchor=north west]0:$b_1$},label={[]below:$a_1$}]{$k$}
-- ++ (2.7,0)node[mycirc,label={[anchor=north east]180:$c_2$},
label={[anchor=north
west]0:$b_2$},label={[]below:$a_2$}]{$k_2$}
-- ++ (0.8,0) edge[dotted] ++ (1.5,0) 
++ (1.5,0) -- 
++(0.8,0)node[mycirc,label={[anchor=north east]180:$c_{D-1}$},
label={[anchor=north
west]0:$b_{D-1}$},label={[]below:$a_{D-1}$}]{$k_{D-1}$}
-- ++ (2.7,0)node[mycirc,label={[anchor=north east]180:$c_D$},
label={[anchor=north
west]0:$b_D$},label={[]below:$a_D$}]{$k_D$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you could have factorized the font `every node/.style={font=\small}`

Comment: @AndréC but the fonts in the circles are not small....

Comment: ok, and `every label` ?